# c# Pass clicked listView cell value to label

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I am able to click on a listView cell and see it on a label right next to the listView but when I click on a other cell I get a Error.

The Code:

```
        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        label2.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        label3.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
    }
```

The Error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument=Value with the value 0 is for index invalid.
>   Parametername: index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't selected items! Listview first deselect current row and then select a new one. You can solve it by Adding:

```
   if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
        label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        label2.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        label3.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question not very clear but the reason of this error is the `Index`, when you click on another cells the value of `Index` equal 0 and it's invalid value.

According to this error:

```
"InvalidArgument=Value with the value 0 is for index invalid. Parametername: index".
```

I hope this help you.